# get the field by field name and set value to it

Tags: grails, groovy

I wanted to set a value to a field in domain class.
For example,

```
class Example {
   String name
   String lastName
}
```

Now, from response I'm getting domain name, object instance id, field name and value. I have to set the value to the field in domain class.

Here I got the values as

```
domainName = 'Example'
instanceId = 1
fieldName = 'name'
valueToSet = 'XYZ'
```

So how should I set value to the field name? May be this is simple but I'm a new with grails and groovy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the domain name, a new domain instance has to be created at runtime. For this to happen, `grailsApplication` has to be injected. Here is a sample which can be modeled after in  Controller or a Service class:

```
class SomeService {
    def grailsApplication

    def someMethod(String domainName, long instanceId, 
                   String fieldName, def valueToSet) {

        Class domainClazz = grailsApplication.domainClasses.find { 
            it.clazz.simpleName == domainName 
        }.clazz

        def domainInstance = domainClazz.get( instanceId )
        domainInstance."$fieldName" = valueToSet

        domainInstance.save()
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this and it worked perfectly fine. But it worked for string values. What ahould I do to get it working for other data types also?

Comment: Good question. I was expecting this question from you and it is good that you ask. Just change the signature of `someMethod` to have `def valueToSet` instead of `String`. This makes sure the static type of `valueToSet` be `Object` and actually type is decided at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You can populate a Grails domain class by assigning a map to its properties, for example from the params in the controller (using that handy automatic binding). E.g.:

ded example=new Example()
example.properties=params

So you can see from this that the domain object can be treated as a set of properties. Which means you can use strings for keys, so you might have something like:

example['name']='XYZ'

I don't know whether that's what you're asking but I hope it helps.